# Windows 10 Run Dialog - Autocompleting

Tags: windows-10

When using the Windows 10 Run Dialog, as soon as I start typing, it displays various files and folders - even ones that have never been opened!

For example, if I type "d:", it will immediately display "d:\folder\file.ext" and so on.

There is nothing in the Run dialog history (checked registry and run CCleaner) I've disabled the autocomplete option in IE

Any suggestions please? I'd happily just disable this altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**From: [How to Enable or Disable AutoSuggest and AutoComplete in Explorer Address Bar and Run Dialog?](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/autosuggest-autocomplete-explorer-address-bar-run-dialog/)**

> - Click Start `Regedit.exe` and go to the following branch:
>
>   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\AutoComplete`
> - Double-click `AutoSuggest` and set its value data to `no`
>
>   (Setting it to no disables auto-suggestions.)
> - Exit the Registry Editor.

**Addendum:** If the value `AutoSuggest` doesn't already exist, create the new String value (REG_SZ) manually and set its data to `no`

Comment: That's spot on - thank you! Only addition would be that if the key AutoSuggest doesn't exist, you'll need to create it.